# Is doubly linking data necessary for MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

Is it necessary to doubly link data for MongoDB, similar to MySQL, where related entries have IDs pointing to each other. In other words, is there any performance difference between:

```
db.events.find({userIds: myId}).fetch()
```

and

```
db.events.find({_id: {$in: [1, 2, 3, 4]} }).fetch()
```

Comment: The difference is between the first being one query, and the second one being many, which is bound to be slower due to networking overhead. If that means that it is "necessary to doubly link data" entirely depends on how you intend to use the database.

Comment: @Thilo I've changed it to make it into one query. Can you clarify what you mean by "How I intend to use the database?" Thanks.

Comment: Now the major difference is that you need to know the list of event ids for the second query, whereas for the first one you just need the userId.

Comment: Yeah, that's the question on doubly linking. Say I already have the first one. Is there any benefit in also doing the second one (redundantly storing the event ids), for some sort of performance increase?

Comment: Assuming you index "userIds" and these two queries return the same results, the main difference is doing a single index lookup on a secondary index vs. multiple lookups against a primary index. Primary indexes are optimized and are slightly faster than secondaries, but the multiple lookups will probably outweigh this. Also in cases where you have a range 1-4, it is more efficient to specify the range $gte:1 and $lte:4, which reduces the index lookups in a btree in this case.

Comment: It is not necessarily redundant. You probably don't have to store the eventId in the user entity at all. And then there is the option of embedded documents. You need to give much more information before anyone can give any advice. Is this 1:N, N:M? How many events can there by per user? What kind of queries do you do? What kind of updates?

Comment: Essentially it's a many-to-many relationship, and I'd like to quickly perform lookups in both directions (given a user, find all events, and given an event, find all users). The trouble with doubly linking, is that an update on both sides, requires a fan-out write, whereas singly linking means only one side requires a fan-out write (for example Users, which are much less likely than events).

Answer (score 0):

Usually, `$in` queries are surprisingly fast, but whether it's the right approach depends on the cardinality of the data (max. events per user, max. users per event) and your query patterns.

In general, the idea of indexes is to avoid having to link back-and-forth. That makes the cumbersome updates you mentioned unnecessary. It's also easier to query, easier to maintain, and is easier to paginate.

The last argument is particularly important but depends on your query patterns: Let's say you want to show the ten most recent events a user attended to. Then you can create an index `{userIds : 1, eventDate: -1}` which will perfectly match the query and doesn't have to pull or iterate *all* the events that the user went to.

If you wanted to do this query using the other method, you'd also have to store the `eventDate` in the user, which seems rather awkward.

On the other hand, if events are huge, you could run into problems with the object size of the event (think 1 million participants). You might want to denormalize the names of participants for display purposes, which makes the object even larger.

If you choose to work with `$in` queries, keep in mind that

1. performance degrades as the array becomes large. I'm not sure what causes this, but I had trouble when the array grew past a one or two thousand(!) elements.
2. If the ids spread very far, MongoDB might have to hit a lot of buckets. This greatly depends on the type of keys you're using, but it can be painful (e.g. if you're using `ObjectIds` and the user attended an event every day you'll probably hit every `_id` bucket you have, also the older ones, which can be expensive).